# Python spark from DenseVector to columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I applied a Logistic Regression in Spark to my data and wants now to split the "probability" column (which is a DenseVector of 2 values each time).

It was a binary classification, so the 'probability' is made of couple like :

`>>> predictions.head(1)`

`[Row(scaledFeatures=SparseVector(10, {4: 4.398, 6: 2.2351}), rawPrediction=DenseVector([4.4453, -4.4453]), probability=DenseVector([0.9829, 0.0171]), prediction=0.0)]`

How can I get a new column with only the second value of 'probability' (here, 0.0171) ?

I tried
`predictions.withColumn('prob', predictions['probability'][1])` but got an error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1314, in withColumn
>       return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sql_ctx)
>     File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in **call**
>     File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 51, in deco
>       raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
>   pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Can't extract value from probability#827;"